# Disable wordpress update on wp-admin dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api, wp-admin

I am looking for a feature where i can bake in my code itself that wordpress update can be disabled from wordpress UI. I dont want to use any plugin definitely dont want to stop wordpress core security updates as well. Do we know if there is any other option like flywheel (which is a wordpress service)  doesn't show wordpress core update on wordpress wp-admin pannel

Answer (score 1):

Create a menu item using `add_menu_page()` function. In it there will be a parameter that asks for the function to be called when this menu is clicked. You can simply create a form on the page with a button like:

`<input type="submit" name="disable_update">`

and the code php will be like

```
PHP Code:
if(isset($_POST['disable_update'])){
 disable_updates();
}
    
function disable_updates() {
 define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false ); 
}
```

**Note**: Use POST as method for the form